# AWS CloudFormation is stuck at CREATE_IN_PROGRESS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I am building a fairly big REST API with AWS Lambda. Language is node.js. There are over 200 functions and few more to come. What EACH of these functions do is connect with a RDS database, get data or save data.

I am deploying this with `aws sam` tool. Below is the `template.yaml`. Please note I am posting just one method because from the outer look all methods looks the same except the endpoints they are pointing.

```
 WSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  xxx-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for xxx-restapi
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3   
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-041f2459dcd921e8e
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-038xxx2d
          - subnet-c4dxxxcb
          - subnet-af5xxxc8

Resources:
  GetAllAccountingTypesFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: xxx-restapi/
      Handler: source/accounting-types/accountingtypes-getall.getallaccountingtypes
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllAccountingTypesAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /accountingtypes/getall
            Method: get
  GetAccountingTypeByIDFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: xxx-restapi/
      Handler: source/accounting-types/accountingtypes-byid.getbyid
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllAccountingTypesAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /accountingtypes/getbyid
            Method: get

LambdaRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                  - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DescribeInstances
                  - ec2:AttachNetworkInterface
                Resource: '*'

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for functions"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
```

All of my methods are fine, they work as expected. However when I try to deploy, this get stuck at `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS`. But, if I reduce the number of functions and try, it works.

I examined the `aws cloud trail` logs, found something like below.

```
ErrorCode: Client.RequestLimitExceeded
Resources: [{"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup","resourceName":"sg-041f245xxxxd921e8e"},{"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Subnet","resourceName":"subnet-af5xxxc8"}]
```

and

```
ErrorCode: Client.DryRunOperation
Resources: [{"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup","resourceName":"sg-041f2459xxxx1e8e"},{"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Subnet","resourceName":"subnet-axxxx3c8"}]
```

There are multiple events like above. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudFormation is probably creating too many functions at once, hence you're hitting a throttling limit. You could probably classify this as a bug in CloudFormation, so I think you should for sure report this to AWS or the CloudFormation team.

That being said, a possible workaround could be to deploy in steps. Adding some Lambda functions with each update. This is going to be a very cumbersome thing to do, but I don't see another way.

You could always make this process easier by using nested stacks (which you can then uncomment one by one). Maybe you could even circumvent the entire throttling limit with it, depending on how CloudFormation deals with that. But I'm not sure about this.

If you're managing so many resources in a single stack, you're also in danger of hitting other CloudFormation limits (especially since SAM abstracts multiple resources behind a single type). So using nested stacks could also prevent you from hitting those limits in the (near) future.

Comment: Finally! Someone with cloud knowledge! Thanks you for the reply. I think I managed to work around by adding `DependsOn` option for every lambda function. now one function get installed after another. Can you please tell me why I am hitting the `Client.DryRunOperation` and how to fix it? For every subnet I have, this error get generated. After having the `DependsOn` it looks like the `DryRun` error is causing at the last method I have. If you like to answer this separately, please check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68906072/aws-how-to-fix-the-cloudformation-dryrunoperation-error

Comment: I have more questions to ask. I know `DependsOn` is a plaster and not a fix. My questions are ( 1 ) How can I add lambda function with each update? Comment and uncomment? Won't aws delete the commented functions thinking they are no longer needed?

Comment: What is nested stacks? Can you point me into a proper `template.yaml` example?

Comment: You can find more information about nested stacks [in the user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html). There's an example available in the [cfn documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#aws-properties-stack--examples) as well.

Comment: Thank you. Can you comment on my other questions as well? The comment - uncomment thing etc?

Comment: You can indeed comment and uncomment in your stack, but if you uncomment something that is already deployed, it will be removed. But if you're running into errors because you're deploying too many resources at once, you can use the trick, since resources that are deployed and haven't changed, won't be redeployed.

Comment: I understand. So this, nested stack thing, do we have to the app into multiple projects? Or use multiple `template.yaml `files ?Or inside the same `template.yaml` we tell it to do the stacking?

Comment: As you can see in the example linked above, they exist in separate files. Whether or not you have them in separate repos or in a single repo is entirely up to you (although I'd advise a single repo).

Comment: ahh... Thank you. One repo multiple files. Great. One last help please. Looking at the code i posted, can you please tell me how many resources I am using? then I can count the total resources used by my app. Current aws limit is 500 resources per stack, if it is not likely to exceed that i would be good.

Comment: It hugely depends on what exactly you have configured. However, you have at least 2 resources per lambda (the function and the role). Then it depends on the events etc you have defined. It might need to create a Lambda Permission type as well. I think you can see the processed template (thus all the resources) in the cloudformation aws console.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: I have created a new question about nested stacks. Can you please check and give some help? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68939710/how-do-i-implement-nested-stacks-in-aws-cloud-formation/68939852#68939852